# Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $u^T A v = u^T v$ for all $u,v \in \Bbb R^n$. Then $A$ = $I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $u^T A v = u^T v$ for all $u,v \in \Bbb R^n$. Then $A$ = $I$.

My thought was that. On the left side, $u^T A v = u^T AI v = (u^T A)A(A^T v) = $.

On the other side, $ u^T v = u^T Iv = u^T(A A^T) v =u^TA A^Tv$.

So we have, $(u^TA) (A^Tv) = (u^T A)A(A^T v)$. Taking the product of the inverse and the parentheses components on both sides, we would be left with $A = I$.

I don't believe that what I wrote is correct because my book gave me the hint: [Let $e_i$ be the unit vector with $0$ in the $j$-entry for all $j \neq i$ with $1$ in the $i$-th entry. Compute $e^T_i A e_j$ and compare with $e^T_i e_j$].

I don't really know how this pertains to what is being asked or how to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931054/is-it-true-that-if-bfx-textt-bfay-bfx-textt-bfby-for-all/1931061#1931061

Comment: @carmichael561 it actually did, but I'm wondering, how does saying
$$ a_{ij}=x^TAy=x^TBy=b_{ij} $$ imply that $A = B$?

Comment: It says that the two matrices have the same entries, which is what is meant by $A=B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u^T B v = 0$ for all $u,v$. If we let $u = Bv$, we see that
$\|Bv\|^2 = 0$ for all $v$, or, in other words, $Bv = 0$ for all $v$. Hence $B = 0$.

Now let $B=A-I$ above.

Alternatively, note that $e_i^T B e_j = [B]_{ij}$. That is, the operation $B \mapsto e_i^T B e_j$ 'picks out' the $ij$ element of $B$.

Comment: I understand the first proof but I think I'm missing the core concept about the second part. How does what you say in the second part imply that $B = 0$?

Comment: Note that $e_i^T (A-I) e_j = [A]_{ij} -\delta_{ij} = 0$ for all $i,j$, so $[A]_{ij} =\delta_{ij} $, or $A=I$.

Comment: That second part makes sense now. In the first part, how did you get from $u = Bv$ to $||Bv||^2 = 0$?

Comment: You have $\|x\|^2 = x^T x$. Then $(Bv)^T B v = \|Bv\|^2$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.